# Merge user permissions

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find a way to merge the rows containing user's resource access permissions. I perform this query passing over a list of groups this user has, and it is possible that one group allows the access to the resource while the other denies.

I have something like this:

> ```
> RESOURCE | ACCESS (F force allow, D deny, A allow)
> res1   | F
> res1   | D
> res2   | A
> res3   | A
> res3   | D
> ```

From these rows I would like to return this:

> ```
> RESOURCE | ACCESS
> res1   | F
> res2   | A
> ```

If i have a Force Allow, it does allow no matter what. If it has an allow + a deny, then deny wins. So in the end i just need to know what is allowed.

Do you guys see how could it be made?

Comment: What even is the logic?  1) why isn't `res3` returned at all? 2) How did you decide that `res1` became `F` and not an `N`?

Comment: Conditionals with checking for an F I'm guessing?

Comment: Okay, and what happens in the case of `res3`?  How come it doesn't return an A or a N?  And, if it is to return, which one wins?

Comment: Edited original question.

Comment: Do you care if the solution is purely SQL rather than including PL/SQL?  While it's certainly possible to implement this sort of logic in a single SQL statement, it's likely going to be much clearer if you create a function that implements whatever logic you need.

Comment: Well, i would prefer a query for sure, but it's not a big deal to have some PL/SQL as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your table is RES and columns are RESOURCE_, ACCESS_. Then you can use this query to get allowed resources.

```
select resource_ , decode(appl_access,3,'F',1,'A') from (
      select r1.resource_, max (decode(r1.access_,'F',3,'D',2,'A',1,0)) 
        appl_access from res r1
      group by r1.resource_)
where appl_access in (1,3);
```

And here is SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/295c9d/1

Answer (score 0):

One of possibilities with function row_number():

```
select res, acc 
  from (
    select res, acc, 
        row_number() over (partition by res 
                           order by case acc when 'F' then 1 
                                             when 'D' then 2
                                             when 'A' then 3
                                    end) rn 
      from test )
  where rn=1 and acc<>'D'
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eaad2e/1)</sup>